# How can I disable the reformat code in the commit changes dialog

Tags: intellij-idea

When I open the commit changes dialog with ctrl-K I have the Before commit / Reformat code ticked. I would like to disable this so that whenever I open the commit changes dialog again it is not ticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable it and commit project, then your setting will be preserved, next time you open this dialog, you should see that it is disabled.

Comment: For some time it didn't worked and I don't know why. No it works again and stay disabled.

Comment: Everytime I upgrade intelliJ this setting is enabled again. Is there anyway to disable it permanently?